# UITableViewCell subclass showing up empty

Tags: uitableview, cell, subclass

I created two prototypes in storyboard with the correct reuse IDs.   The debugger stops in various breakpoints inside my custom cells but yet the table view still displays blank cells.   What gives?

Thanks in advance

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellID = @"CellIdentifier";
static NSString *CommentCellID = @"CommentCellIdentifier";

// for iOS6+ not specifying forIndexPath:indexPath causes assertion when endUpdates is called

NSUInteger sectionNumber = [indexPath section];
switch (sectionNumber) {
    case 2: {

        // Try to dequeue a cell and create one if necessary
        SDCCommentCell *commentCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CommentCellID];
        if (commentCell == nil) {
            commentCell = [[SDCCommentCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CommentCellID];
            //cell.cellInsetWidth = kSDCCellInsetWidth;
            commentCell.delegate = self;
        }

        PFObject *object = [parseObjectsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [commentCell setUser:[object objectForKey:kSDCActivityFromUserKey]];
        [commentCell setContentText:[object objectForKey:kSDCActivityContentKey]];
        [commentCell setDate:[object createdAt]];
        return commentCell;
    }
    default: {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.. I just figured it out. I forgot to add in the `viewDidLoad()`

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[SDCCommentCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CommentCellIdentifier"];
```